# Transliteration in typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js

Firstly, please check this: http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=advanced

You can paste all the content of that JSON to here : http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Now you can see the content of that JSON is in Vietnamese. And well, I want when user search they can search with UTF-8 character.

For example:
You type in the search box character 'ô', the suggestion should displays. (Typeahead.js now can't do that).

Is there any way can do my requirements ?

Edit :

You can see a live demo at http://www.luyencong.net (type a character in search box)

Comment: Could you create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: You can check a live demo here : http://www.luyencong.net/
In the search box, type something like `ô` or `đ`

Comment: I mean without seeing any code, it's quite difficult to figure out the problem. At least edit your question to add how did you initialize the  `typeahead` in JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution, but you could take advantage of custom tokens to get transliteration support. For example, if you had the following datum:

```
{
  "value": "limón fútbol"
}
```

By default, it would get tokenized into `['limón', 'fútbol']`. If you explicitly set the tokens yourself however, you could do something like this:

```
{
  "value": "limón fútbol",
  "tokens": ["limon", "limón", "futbol", "fútbol"]
}
```

Now if you searched for `limon` or `futbol`, this datum would be show as a suggestion.

Comment: I tried. But not work :( Please take a look in my JSON, is that correct ? http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=advanced

Comment: The values in `tokens` need to already be tokenized. So rather than `tokens: ["Hoang Kim Dong", "An Su"]`, it should be `tokens: ["Hoang", "Kim", "Dong", "An", "Su"]`.